# Convergence in distribution of parameters of exponential family

Tags: convergence, central-limit-theorem, exponential-family

I am taking a course in inference where we have to find an approximate confidence interval for a Rayleigh distributed variable.

The correct answer to this question states:

*Since we have an exponential family of distributions we know that for large $n$:*
$$\frac{\hat \theta - \theta}{\sqrt{V(\hat \theta)}} \overset{D}{\longrightarrow} N(0,1).$$

The book we use is Casella and Bergers Statistical Inference. I have looked in it and also googled quite a bit without finding an explanation of this exact result.

My question is first, is this always true for any parameter of an exponential distribution? Where can I read up on this?

Comment: What kind of estimator is $\hat\theta$?

Comment: In the context of the answer it is an MLE estimator, but it is unclear if this is specific to MLE, I am not sure.

Comment: For MLE in regular exponential family (under some regularity conditions) this is always true. But asymptotic normality is a general result and it usually depends on what exactly $\hat\theta$ is for us to say if it is asymptotically normal or not.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You dont happen to have a good recommendation for further reading?

Comment: Apart from Casella-Berger there is Hogg & Craig's textbook on mathematical statistics. For large sample theory in particular there is a book by Lehmann and also one by Ferguson. You might also take a look at DasGupta's *Asymptotic Theory of Statistics and Probability*.